# Is it safe to enable MSDTC (Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator) on our server

Tags: entity-framework, transactionscope, windows-server, msdtc

I'm always worried about using two instances of `DbContext` that would require distributed transaction coordinator, especially when I'm using a library like `SimpleMembership` which has its own connection to the database.

This problem is always an issue in my case. For example I'm using `SimpleMembership` provider for my application's user accounts and I want to save a user with additional information, like company. So without MSDTC enable I can't do this inside a transaction. So it is possible that inconsistent data is inserted into the database.

So my question is should I worry about this problem and try to find a better solution or I can just enable MSDTC on my server and don't worry about it? Is there any consequences of enabling MSTDC ?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd check how it plays with your high availability story. AFAIK mirroring failovers are problematic with MSDTC.